# Unexpected blocking behavior

Tags: nginx, nginx-unit

I have a Java web app with a HTTP GET method with this code (inside a servlet):

```
        Certificate certificate = Observable.range(1, 10)
                .delay(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .filter(integer -> {
                    try {
                        LOG.info("AUTHORIZE ATTEMPTS: " + integer);
                        order.update();
                    } catch (AcmeException e) {
                        Exceptions.propagate(e);
                    }
                    return order.getStatus() == Status.VALID;
                }).map(integer -> {
                    Certificate cert = order.getCertificate();
                    return cert;
                }).toBlocking().first();
```

The problem with this in relation to NGINX Unit is that when running in localhost using Jetty maven plugin, nothing is wrong, however when running with NGINX Unit with this application config:

```
{
  "applications": {
    "backend": {
      "processes": 1,
      "type": "java",
      "options": [
        "-Dlog_path=/var/log/backend-server-0-SNAPSHOT.log"
      ],
      "webapp": "/var/www/backend-server-0-SNAPSHOT.war"
    }
  },
  "listeners": {
    "*:8080": {
      "application": "backend"
    }
  }
}
```

The Java code above blocks the whole web application, meaning, no other HTTP request can be handled by the Java web app for a duration of 30 seconds, since,  `Observable.range(1, 10)` with 3 seconds delay.

I wonder why NGINX Unit is behaving this way. The expected behavior is that the web application should still be able to serve requests.

Comment: From what I see from your explanation, your Java code is blocking the web app for 30s. So it makes sens that if you set the number process to one. Only one process will be started and will be blocked for 30s because of your code.

You can either increase the number of process or have a non-blocking app.

Comment: @Victor by design my applicaiton can only scale vertically, thus using Unit and adding more into the "processes" configuration block breaks my application due to the embedded database locking. In other words it only works with `"processes": 1`